# How to create a json file using the rapidjson library from vector<string> data?

Tags: c++, json, string, vector, rapidjson

How can i create json file (string) from:

`vector<string>m_paths`

I have code:

```
 rapidjson::Document jsonfile;
    jsonfile.SetObject();
    rapidjson::Document::AllocatorType& jsonallocator = jsonfile.GetAllocator();


    std::vector<String>::iterator itm;
    rapidjson::Value paths(rapidjson::kArrayType);

    for(itm = m_paths.begin(); itm != m_paths.end(); ++itm)
    {
        //rapidjson::Value jValueConverting;
       // jValueConverting.SetString(GetLogRpl().c_str(), (rapidjson::SizeType)GetLogRpl().size(), jsonallocator);
    }

    jsonfile.AddMember("paths", paths, jsonallocator);


    rapidjson::StringBuffer jsonstring;
    rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::StringBuffer> jsonwriter(jsonstring);
    jsonfile.Accept(jsonwriter);

    String fullJsonString = jsonstring.GetString();

    return fullJsonString;
```

I must use rapidjson library and don't know what i should do after creating allocator. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to meet the standards outlined there.

Comment: I doubt you need to worry about the allocator. If you do, rapidjson is very badly designed. Allocators are for advanced programming where you might not have access to the normal heap.

Answer (score 1):

```
        StringBuffer sb;
        PrettyWriter writer(sb);
        writer.StartObject();
        writer.String(_T("paths"));
        writer.StartArray();
        std::vector<String>::iterator itm;
        for(itm = m_paths.begin(); itm != m_paths.end(); ++itm)
        {
            writer.String(*itm);
        }
        writer.EndArray();
        writer.EndObject();

        std::string fullJsonString = sb.GetString();
```